# Netsuite Script to add charge on sales order based on specific customer

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I am trying to create a script to add discount rate on sales order based on specific customer. I tired different methods to match the customer but its not working and discount rate is not working either.

```
function totalQuantity() {
    var lineCount = parseInt( nlapiGetLineItemCount('item'));
    var qty;
    var totalQty = parseInt("0");

    for(x = 1; x<=lineCount; x++) {
        qty = nlapiGetLineItemValue('item', 'quantity', x);

        if (qty == null || qty.length == 0 || isNaN(qty)) {
            qty = 0;
        }

        totalQty = parseInt( totalQty + parseInt(qty) );
    }

    nlapiSetFieldValue('custbody7', totalQty);
    totalQty = parseInt (totalQty * parseInt("5"));
    nlapiSetFieldValue('discountitem' , '18732');
    nlapiSetFieldValue('discountrate' , totalQty);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: When is this function getting called?

Comment: its being called on save.

Comment: I think @erictgrubaugh is asking what script entry point is this being called in? This is relevant because you must interact with the record in different ways if this is a Client Script saveRecord, a User Event beforeSubmit, or a User Event afterSubmit. Without that information you will not get an accurate answer.